# Implementing an efficient decision table algorithm with don't care values

Tags: algorithm, performance, decision-tree

I'm trying to find an algorithm to implement a decision table efficiently,

The problem is when you have a "don't care" values.

For example consider the following table:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3


     1      2       

     1      2        4
```

For the input (1,2,3) the match should be the first row (1,2, ).

Any suggestions/references?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of why `(1,2,3)` should match the first and not also the second row?

Comment: the empty value of column3 in the first row represents any value(or don't care), the second row is strictly matches to (1,2,4) input only

Comment: OK...and what tool/language do you plan to use for this?

Comment: I'm in the java/scala domain languages

Comment: Then you should have phrased your question using Java/Scala, not an HTML page with a table.  What you asked, in its current form, is too broad.

Comment: I fixed the table, I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to solve this problem, its not have to be a java/scala implementation

Comment: Your question is still too broad IMO, because the answer would totally depend on the language.  If your table were a SQL database table, then the answer would be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I don't agree, even if it was sql table the solution is not straight forward...